# Kieran healy emacs 25.1.1 starter kit install error magit package unavailable

Tags: linux, emacs, magit, melpa

I'm trying to install Kieran Healy's Emacs Starter Kit (https://github.com/kjhealy/emacs-starter-kit) on linux arch (I have also tried on a Mint installation, running into the same errors), but I'm having quite some trouble.

After deleting my ~/.emacs.d and installing the starter kit, emacs starts installing packages, but runs into a 'Package magit- is not available'-error. Other Melpa-packages are installing fine. An m-x refresh-contents doesn't make a difference, and neither does an m-x install-package magit.

I am able to install magit if I temporarily rename my .d.emacs and run with a fresh .emacs, and if I, after installation of magit, enable the starter kit again, emacs will load the installed magit-package perfectly fine. It does stall again, on several other packages (ipython, typopunct), in exactly the same manner.

If I comment out the 'require of these three packages, installation seems to work, but stalls on a not found 'ob-shell (as in this question: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21366/should-i-have-removed-shell-t-to-clear-an-ob-shell-initialization-error). This is in addition to several other errors that seem to indicate a not-complete installation as I try to continue use of emacs.

I have not been able to find any documentation relating to this. Appearently, missing packages are not uncommon with old emacs-installations, but as I am using a 25.1.1 install, this does not seem to be the problem.

Any ideas going forward?

Comment: See what you have in `package-archives` and `package-pinned-packages`. What you describe is consistent with the situation where the `init.el` you're using doesn't include the necessary archive in `package-archives` or has `magit` pinned to a wrong archive.

Comment: FYI: there's been a recent update to the starter-kit to address the issue with `magit`. That update doesn't yet fix the trouble with `ipython`. Is that a package that used to be, but no longer is, available for emacs?

Answer (score 3):

The issue with `magit` was indeed solved a little while ago. The issue with `ipython` that apc raised exists because that's a package from the Marmalade repo, which needs to be added manually to the list of repositories. To install it, just execute the following code in the console.

```
M-x package-refresh-contents [RET]
M-: (add-to-list 'package-archives '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
M-x package-refresh-contents [RET]
M-x package-install [RET] ipython
```